# Hidden redirection code

Tags: redirect, hidden

I want to redirect to another web page and this redirection depends on another redirection which must be hidden and not shown to the customers.

Have you any solutions for that please?

Comment: If you perform another hidden redirection, then the browser's back button will return the user to the page prior to the first redirect.  There is no additional work on your part.  Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: The problem is that when I do two redirection, I will be redirected to the first redirection and I want that I will be redirected to the second redirection and the first redirection will be hidden.

Comment: And so do that.  I'm missing the problem here.  Make the page that you arrive at after the first redirect then redirect you to a second page in a non-hidden way.

Comment: Thank you very much for our help. I don't understand your solution, could you give me an example with more details please

Comment: Well the first redirect is done by the server in response to a page request, right?  The destination page is simply another request like the first.  If you wish also this request to be a redirect, then you'll need to treat requests to this second page as yet another redirect, and only the first redirect will be hidden.  Are you unclear on how to do a redirect?

Comment: I put the second redirection in a second file and I still have problem on how link the first file that contains the first redirection with the second because the second redirection is linked to eht first redirection which must be executed before the second and hidden. I try to execute the first file from the second but it stills the same problem the first redirection is executed and not the second